# Color box Light box in Jquery

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Do color box should have two separate images ? one for the normal html page and another one for the color box image ?

I searched this link http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/guide/  and cannot find the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link for colorbox can be either text or a smaller thumbnail image:

Text link:

```
 <a class='gallery' href='fullSizeImage.jpg'>Photo</a>
```

Thumbnail Link:

```
 <a class='gallery' href='fullSizeImage.jpg'><img source"thumbnailImage.jpg" /></a>
```

So if you want a thumbnail, then you need two images. A Thumb and a Full Size